# Spring Data Redis: Failed to convert from type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.StreamRecords$ByteMapBackedRecord] to type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, deserialization

I've been struggling with this exception from Spring Redis Streams when I try to convert a message from the Stream to my entity. I believe it is occurring due to an issue with the Redis Stream's default Deserializer, however not sure how to resolve.

When I send this message to the Redis stream

> XADD my-stream * from john to smith type Request

I get this exception from my spring boot service

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.StreamRecords$ByteMapBackedRecord] to type [com.example.messaging.Dto.NotificationMessage] for value 'MapBackedRecord{recordId=1639826917707-0, kvMap={[B@55ab97aa=[B@510458ff, [B@5b7e99c1=[B@4141b49e, [B@12840469=[B@6aa14d0}}'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must not be null!
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamPollTask.convertRecord(StreamPollTask.java:198) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamPollTask.deserializeAndEmitRecords(StreamPollTask.java:176) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamPollTask.doLoop(StreamPollTask.java:148) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamPollTask.run(StreamPollTask.java:132) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.Record.of(Record.java:81) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.MapRecord.toObjectRecord(MapRecord.java:147) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.StreamObjectMapper.toObjectRecord(StreamObjectMapper.java:138) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.StreamOperations.map(StreamOperations.java:577) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.DefaultStreamMessageListenerContainer.lambda$getDeserializer$2(DefaultStreamMessageListenerContainer.java:240) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamPollTask.convertRecord(StreamPollTask.java:196) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Config Class:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Autowired
    private StreamListener<String, ObjectRecord<String, NotificationMessage>> streamListener;

    @Bean
    public Subscription subscription(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) throws UnknownHostException {
        StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions<String, ObjectRecord<String, NotificationMessage>> options
                = StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions.builder()
                .pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .targetType(NotificationMessage.class)
                .build();

        StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, ObjectRecord<String, NotificationMessage>> listenerContainer =
                StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(redisConnectionFactory, options);

        Subscription subscription = listenerContainer.receive(StreamOffset.latest("my-stream"), streamListener);

        listenerContainer.start();
        return subscription;
    }
}
```

NotificationMessage Dto:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NotificationMessage {
    private String id;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String type;
}
```

Comment: I am facing this as well, have you been able to resolve it by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

### Simple code example (spring-data-redis:2.6.4):

###### Stream record:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@TypeAlias("com.pet.streams.User")
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}
```

###### Streams config:

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.Consumer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.ObjectRecord;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.ReadOffset;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.StreamOffset;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.stream.Subscription;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.time.Duration;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class StreamsConfig {
    private final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    public StreamsConfig(RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public StreamListener<String, ObjectRecord<String, User>> userStreamListener() {
        // handle message from stream
        return message -> log.info(message.toString());
    }

    @Bean
    public Subscription subscription(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory, StreamListener<String, ObjectRecord<String, User>> userStreamListener) throws UnknownHostException {
        String streamKey = "streams:users";
        String groupName = "cg";
        createConsumerGroupIfNotExists(streamKey, groupName);
        StreamOffset<String> streamOffset = StreamOffset.create(streamKey, ReadOffset.lastConsumed());
        StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions<String, ObjectRecord<String, User>> options = StreamMessageListenerContainer
                .StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions
                .builder()
                .pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                .targetType(User.class)
                .build();
        StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, ObjectRecord<String, User>>  listenerContainer = StreamMessageListenerContainer
                .create(redisConnectionFactory, options);
        StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamReadRequest<String> readRequest = StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamReadRequest.builder(streamOffset)
                .consumer(Consumer.from(groupName, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()))
                .cancelOnError((err) -> false)  // do not stop consuming after error
                .errorHandler((err) -> log.error(err.getMessage()))
                .build();
        Subscription subscription = listenerContainer.register(readRequest, userStreamListener);
        listenerContainer.start();
        return subscription;
    }

    private void createConsumerGroupIfNotExists(String streamKey, String groupName){
        try {
            redisTemplate.opsForStream().createGroup(streamKey, groupName);
        }
        catch (RedisSystemException ex){
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

### Testing:

Enter `XADD streams:users * _class com.pet.streams.User name Bob age 30` in `redis-cli` to add one record to stream. Should be consumed by running app properly (logged).

Enter `XADD streams:users * name Bob age 30` without `_class` field. Should log an exception (mentioned above).

### Conclusion:

Spring Data sets `_class` field automatically on publishing new record to stream. But if you use external systems to publish messages to redis streams, make sure that you have provided `_class` field in the record. Or override default mappers.

### Extra:

Check `DefaultRedisTypeMapper` class. Replace it with custom mapper. I haven't tried it, but it looks possible.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem, I had some messages serialized into redis from one service and deserialized in a different service and it would complain that it could not convert types even if the objects were identical, except the classpath. I had to give my redis listener the model with the exact classpath from the source service and it would work.

Someone here had an issue using typealias to try and solve the same problem:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1095

I'm still trying to find a more elegant solution maybe with the typealias annotation in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the streammessagelistenercontaineroptions object, do not specify the target type. That is, remove `". TargetType (notificationmessage. Class)"`. The reason for this problem lies in the serialization of the internal classes of redis stream.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the `ObjectRecord<S,V>` you can just use the default one, which is `MapRecord<String, String, String>`. So the implementation will be like this

```
public Subscription subscription(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory, StreamListener<String, ObjectRecord<String, User>> userStreamListener) throws UnknownHostException {
    String streamKey = "streams:users";
    String groupName = "cg";
    createConsumerGroupIfNotExists(streamKey, groupName);
    StreamOffset<String> streamOffset = StreamOffset.create(streamKey, ReadOffset.lastConsumed());

    //removed the StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions

    StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, ObjectRecord<String, User>>  listenerContainer = StreamMessageListenerContainer
                    .create(redisConnectionFactory);
    StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamReadRequest<String> readRequest = StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamReadRequest.builder(streamOffset)
                    .consumer(Consumer.from(groupName, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()))
                    .cancelOnError((err) -> false)  // do not stop consuming after error
                    .errorHandler((err) -> log.error(err.getMessage()))
                    .build();
    Subscription subscription = listenerContainer.register(readRequest, userStreamListener);
    listenerContainer.start();
    return subscription;
}
```

In the handler, you can just get the value as `Map<String,String>` by using `Record.getValue()` and Map it manually to your object. You can use a library like `MapStruct` to develop the mapper with ease.